# Subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ that preserves a covering map

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be any compact, connected surface of constant negative curvature $-1$. It is known that there is a covering map $\rho: \mathbb H \to X$ that is a local isometry, where
$\mathbb H$ is the hyperbolic upper half plane.

Let

$$\Gamma:=\{\gamma\in SL(2,\mathbb R): 
\rho(\gamma z)=\rho(z), \forall z\in \mathbb H \}$$

I wonder how to prove that $\Gamma$ is discrete and that $\Gamma \backslash SL(2,\mathbb R)$ is compact.

For the discreteness, I feel like we need to use the local homeomorphism property of $\rho$ somehow but I can't formula it into a rigorous proof.

For the compactness, I know usually one wants to
embed $\Gamma \backslash SL(2,\mathbb R)$ into a compact space as a closed subspace. One way to do this is by

$$f: \Gamma \backslash SL(2,\mathbb R) \to X, \Gamma x \mapsto \rho(x).$$

This map is well-defined, continuous and injective. As long as I could show that its image is closed in $X$, we are done (but I don't know how to show it rigorously).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with covering space theory.

First of all, the deck transformation group $D(\rho)$ of the covering map $\rho : \mathbb H \to X$ is defined to be the group of all homeomorphism $h : \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$ such that $\rho(hz)=\rho(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb H$.

Obviously $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $D(\rho)$. The key is to prove that $\Gamma = D(\rho)$, and to do this one has to prove that for each $h \in D(\rho)$, the homeomorphism $h : \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$ is an isometry. The first step is to use the fact that $\rho$ is a locally isometric covering map. Using this, one proves that $h$ is also a local isometry, because for each $x \in \mathbb H$ with $y = h(x) \in \mathbb H$, there exist open subsets $U \subset X$, $V_x \subset \mathbb H$, and $V_y \subset \mathbb H$ such that

1. $x \in V_x$ and $y \in V_y$,
2. $\rho_x = \rho \mid V_x : V_x \to U$ is an isometry,
3. $\rho_y = \rho \mid V_y : V_y \to U$ is an isometry,
4. $h \mid V_x = \rho_y^{-1} \circ \rho_x : V_x \to V_y$ is therefore an isometry.

The next step is to prove that a bijective local isometry of $\mathbb H$ is an isometry of $\mathbb H$, but I'll leave that for you to ponder.

So, knowing that $\Gamma=D(\rho)$, discreteness of $\Gamma$ follows from a general theorem that the deck transformation group of any covering map acts [properly discontinuously,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions): to see why this follows, if $\Gamma$ is not discrete then it has a non-identity subsequence converging to the identity in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$, and one can show that this contradicts proper discontinuity using the fact that the Lie group topology on $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ is the same as the compact open topology with respect to the action of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb H$.

Finally, cocompactness of $\Gamma=D(\rho)$ follows from the fact that the orbit space is homeomorphic to $X$ which is cocompact.

Comment: Just make sure that I understand the sentence "This is where one uses that ρ is a local isometry: it follows that h is also a local isometry.".      I guess here you mean we are using the chain rule for differentials. But deck transformations are just continuous maps but not necessarily smooth, right?

Comment: In general, yes, deck transformations are just continuous maps (well, homeomorphisms, which is somewhat more than just continuous). The aptness of your guess regarding the chain rule for diffeomorphism depends on whether by "isometry" you mean [metric space isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) or [Riemannian isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry#Manifolds); which one you intend is not clear from the context of your question.

Comment: I've added some details regarding why $h$ is also a local isometry.